# SyntaxError: Unexpected Token '?' discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm using discord.js version 12.5.3, I also am using replit for my project. I keep getting this error: [image]

This is my code:

```
export default class Deps {
  static #instances = new Map();

  static get(type) {
    return this.#instances.get(type)
      ?? this.add(type, new type());
  }

  static add(type, instance) {
    return this.#instances
      .set(type, instance)
      .get(type);
  }
}
```

Comment: The `return` statement has an implicit semicolon so if `get(type)` returns a falsy value it _won't_ then try `this.add(type, new type())`. Also, use `PascalCase` for classes, not `camelCase`.

Comment: i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you running? Run `node -v` to find out.

Comment: According to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/ the `??` operator is supported by NodeJS 14.0 or later. It is also supported by NodeJS 13 if you use the `--harmony-nullish` flag (you also might want to enable `--harmony-optional-chaining` too). If you're using an older version of Node then you probably should update.

Comment: I'm on version 12.16.1 but i can't update it because there is no download feature. Is there any way to do this through the shell or console? (Thanks so much for your help so far)

Comment: I updated it thank you so much Dai, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: The `??` needs to be on the same line as the `return` statement:

```
export default class Deps {
  static #instances = new Map();

  static get(type) {
    return this.#instances.get(type) ?? this.add(type, new Type()); // <-- Like this
  }

  static add(type, instance) {
    return this.#instances
      .set(type, instance)
      .get(type);
  }
}
```

---

**Longer answer**: [The `return` statement in JavaScript has special *automatic semicolon insertion* ("ASI") rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) which mean you need to have the *entire expression* on a single line, or use parentheses so that your `return` statement's expression clearly spans multiple lines.

So you *could* also do this:

```
export default class Deps {
  static #instances = new Map();

  static get(type) {
    return ( this.#instances.get(type)    // <-- Opening `(` here.
        ?? this.add(type, new Type())
    );                                    // <-- Closing `)` here.
  }

  static add(type, instance) {
    return this.#instances
      .set(type, instance)
      .get(type);
  }
}
```

---

<sub>Before I started using TypeScript I used to get stung by `return` ASI rules all the time without realising it: it's a frequent source of bugs.</sub>